# What are the different ways to get ascended gear?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I came back to Guild Wars 2 after a long period, and at that time exotic was the highest tier for armor and weapons, but now ascended gear exists in those slots.

I found out that the normal way to get ascended gear is to level armorsmith and weaponsmith to 500 and craft them, creating account bounded gear.

As crafting isn't really my thing, I would like to avoid it as much as possible, so is there any other way to get ascended gear ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated, ascended gear can be crafted.

---

**Crafting**

*Ascended weapons* are crafted using ascended materials and a complex process. Players will need to purchase a Recipe: Ascended Inscription and use it to acquire the recipe for the prefix they want. Players also need to purchase an ascended weapon recipe for the appropriate weapon type; a greatsword requires a Recipe: Ascended Greatsword for example. The prefix of the weapon recipe and the inscription recipe have to match. The components for the weapons require the equivalent of tier 7 crafting materials for each crafting profession.

*Ascended armor* is crafted using ascended materials and a complex process. Players will need to purchase a Recipe: Ascended Insignia and use it to acquire the recipe for the prefix they want. Players also need to purchase an ascended armor recipe for the appropriate piece of armor; a heavy helm requires a Recipe: Ascended Heavy Helm for example. The prefix of the armor recipe and the insignia recipe have to match. The components for the armor requires the equivalent of tier 7 crafting materials for each crafting profession.

**Materials needed**

*Light armor*

- 6 Gossamer Insignia
- 30 Glob of Dark Matter
- 120 Pile of Crystalline Dust
- 6 Augur's Stone
- 15 Dragonite Ingot
- 15 Empyreal Star
- 15 Bloodstone Brick
- 36 Bolt of Damask
- 6 Elonian Leather Square
- 720 Spool of Gossamer Thread

*Medium armor*

- 6 Gossamer Insignia
- 30 Glob of Dark Matter
- 120 Pile of Crystalline Dust
- 6 Augur's Stone
- 15 Dragonite Ingot
- 15 Empyreal Star
- 15 Bloodstone Brick
- 24 Bolt of Damask
- 18 Elonian Leather Square
- 720 Spool of Gossamer Thread

*Heavy armor*

- 6 Gossamer Insignia
- 30 Glob of Dark Matter
- 120 Pile of Crystalline Dust
- 6 Augur's Stone
- 15 Dragonite Ingot
- 15 Empyreal Star
- 15 Bloodstone Brick
- 25 Bolt of Damask
- 16 Deldrimor Steel Ingot
- 360 Spool of Gossamer Thread
- 150 Thermocatalytic Reagent

As you can see ascended gear requires a lot of base materials (pretty obvious since its currently the highest tier armor). There IS another way to get ascended gear however.

---

**Ascended chests**

Ascended chests drop from [Fractals of the Mists](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Fractals_of_the_Mists), [Tequatl the Sunless](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Tequatl_the_Sunless), [exotic champion loot bags](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Champion_loot_bag), reward chests of [Guild Missions](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Guild_mission) and give any armor piece with a given prefix. The prefix of the chest corresponds to the prefix for the ascended armor, for example Occam's Armor Chest contains Occam's "Carrion" armor and for example Beigarth's Weapon Chest contains Beigarth's "Knight" weapons.

---

Source : http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Ascended_armor

Comment: perfect answer for armor, crafting is similar for weapons, but are there ways to get ascended weapons from chests or another way ?

Comment: Weapons are the same as the armor only since the weapons differ heavily in the required materials i didnt include that in my answer. I'll add a tiny bit to my answer though just so its clear that the process of weapons is the same as the armor.

Comment: Now the answer is perfect !

Comment: @Shunwoo I'm with you, never been huge into the crafting side of thing! Will have to start searching for these ascended chests!